# Unequal border radius

Tags: html, css

Is there a CSS3 way of creating a border radius like the one on the attached image? [Border Radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rved0.jpg)

When I use border-radius it applies the curves to both sides.

Comment: For reference, see the examples here: [border-radius @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).

Answer (score 4):

```css
#border {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #333;
  border-radius: 150px/30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">

</div>
```

You can create elliptical borders by adding a slash "/" between the border-radius values:

```
border-radius: 150px/30px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use two values each, like

```
border-top-left-radius: 80px 35px;
border-top-right-radius: 80px 35px;
```

Here's a codepen showing a DIV like with those settings:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOZrMr

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
border-top-left-radius
```

you can specify the radius by corner

[docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-top-left-radius.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Look [border-radius](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#border-radius).

```css
.radius {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10em/1em;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.radius > img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="radius">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300&text=Image" alt="Image">
</div>
```